# How to Show Context Menu for some row in gridView

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that it bind to a data table.I want to add context ment for rows that has a condition. I use this code in `RowDataBound` event:

```
if (e.Row.Enabled == true && e.Row.Cells[6].Enabled == true)
        {
            e.Row.CssClass = "HasMenu";
        }
```

now I write this code to show context menu on grid:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#menu').click(function () {
            $('#menu').hide();
        });
        $(document).click(function () {
            $('#menu').hide();
        });


        $("#" + '<%= GridView1.ClientID %>').bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
            $('#menu').css({
                top: e.pageY + 'px',
                left: e.pageX + 'px'
            }).show();

            return false;

        });
    });
```

the problem is I don't show any context menu(not explorer context menu and not my custom context menu) on the rows that has no `HasMenu` css class and show Context menu for rows that has `HasMenu` css class .what change need on my script?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're listening to the `contextmenu` event for the entire gridview:

```
$("#" + '<%= GridView1.ClientID %>')
```

You'd need to change that to individual rows:

```
$('#" + '<%= GridView1.ClientID %> rowselector.HasMenu')
```

Where `rowselector` is however a row is defined in your markup.

For instance, if a row is a `<TR>` then you would write

```
$("#" + '<%= GridView1.ClientID %> tr.HasMenu')
```

Otherwise, if the rows are child `<DIV>` elements you might want to write something like

```
$("#" + '<%= GridView1.ClientID %> > div.HasMenu')
```

Note that you're concatenating two plain strings, there's no javascript variables involved. You might as well write:

```
$('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> rowselector.HasMenu')
```

Comment: It cause IE context menu appear on rows that has not `HasMenu` class

Comment: @Kerezo: Yes, I didn't notice at first that you added the listener to the entire menu. See my edit.

Comment: return false during contextmenu handler if browser is IE and Row doesnot have HasMenu class

Comment: thankd but please help me I don't know How I can write this: `Rows doea not have HasMenu` in selector

Comment: @Kerezo: The full selector would come down to how a row is defined in your markup, but whichever the row selector is, you could append it with `.HasMenu` to select only if it has the class, with  `:not(.HasMenu')` to select only if it *lacks* the class, or `.hasClass('HasMenu')` to test if it has the class.